# Notation for intervals

Tags: notation, math-history

I have frequently encountered both $\langle a,b \rangle$ and $[a,b]$ as notation for closed [intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Notations_for_intervals). I have mostly encountered $(a,b)$ for open intervals, but I have also seen $]a,b[$. I recall someone calling the notation with $[a,b]$ and $]a,b[$ as *French* notation.

> - What are the origins of the two notations?
> - Is the name *French notation* correct? Are they used frequently in France? Or were they perhaps prevalent in French mathematical community at some point? (In this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18593/what-are-the-worst-notations-in-your-opinion/18712#18712) Bourbaki is mentioned in connection with the notation $]a,b[$.)

---

Since several answerers have already mentioned that they have never seen $\langle a,b \rangle$ to be used for closed intervals, I have tried to look for some occurrences for this.
The best I can come up with is the article on [Czech Wikipedia](http://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28matematika%29), where these notations are called Czech notation and French notation. Using $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ is called English notation in that article. (I am from Central Europe, too, so it is perhaps not that surprising that I have seen this notation in lectures.)

I also tried to google for [interval langle](http://www.google.com/search?q=interval+langle)
or ["closed interval" langle](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22closed+interval%22+langle). Surprisingly, this lead me to a [question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380859/let-alpha-langle-a-b-rangle-longrightarrow-mathbbr2-be-a-continuous-fun#comment815612_380859) where this notation is used for open interval.

Comment: I can confirm that $\langle a,\,b \rangle$ is/was sometimes used as notation for closed intervals, for example in "Einführung in die Funktionalanalysis", F. Hirzebruch/W. Scharlau; BI Hochschultaschenbücher, Bibliographisches Institut, Mannheim, 1971.

Comment: See also: [Why is American and French notation different for open intervals (x, y) vs. \]x, y\[?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/142/why-is-american-and-french-notation-different-for-open-intervals-x-y-vs-x) at HSM

Answer (score 15):

As a French student, all my math teachers (as well as the physics/biology/etc. ones) always used the $[a,b]$ and $]a,b[$ (and the "hybrid" $[a,b[$ and $]a,b]$) notations.
We also, for *integer* intervals $\{a,a+1,...,b\}$, use the \llbracket\rrbracket notation (in LateX, package {stmaryrd}): $[[ a,b ]]$.

I have never seen the $\langle a,b \rangle$ notation used for intervals, though (only for inner products or more exotic binary operations).

Answer (score 6):

The notations $(a,b]$ and $]a,b]$ are both part of [ISO 31-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11), an international standard for mathematical notation.  In the U.S. the former is more common.  A few comments comparing the two can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/181751/73324), including support for the "French notation" nomenclature.

I have never seen $\langle a,b\rangle$ for closed intervals.