# What's the difference between ]a,b[ and (a,b)?

Tags: notation

Is there any difference between $]a,b[$ and $(a,b)$? If there is no difference, what would be the motivation of using $]a,b[$ over $(a,b)$?

Comment: @DavidMitra When I first saw it, I thought (incorrectly) that $]a,b[$ meant $\mathbb R\backslash (a,b)$, so I personally don't think this notation is clearer.

Comment: @Ragnar I actually agree with you. I also first thought in that way.

Comment: Related question: [Notation for intervals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. They both refer to "the open interval from $a$ to $b$." The "advantage" of using $]a,b[$ is that it can't be mistaken for an ordered pair.

Comment: and the advantage of $(a,b)$ is that the brackets can't be mistaken to point in the other direction (in more comples expressions)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I happen to find the $]a,b[$ notation confusing, especially when it's in a longer mathematical expression. But the ability to immediately distinguish $]a,b[$ from an ordered pair is the explanation I've heard for the "backwards bracket" notation from those who do use it (I happen not to be someone who does).

Comment: I never liked the $]a,b[$ notation. But it does have the advantage of being visually suggestive as to whether the endpoints are included or not. Same for the closed and half-open variants. The choice of meaning for $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ can't be divined from the notation, making that an arbitrary decision about which one means what.