# Notation $(a,b)$ for $]a,b[$.

Tags: notation

Is there any logic or justification for the notation $(a,b)$ to represent $]a,b[$? To me this notation is very ambiguous and confusing because it looks like a couple of numbers and not an interval.

Thanks.

Comment: But when you talk about real numbers, you don't think about $(a,b)$ as a point in $\mathbb R^2$, right? I guess in most cases, there will be no confusion with proper context.

Comment: It's just a matter of convention, I was confused too when I first saw the notation $(a,b)$ because in italian schools they usually teach the square brackets ones, but once you know that they are equivalent I don't think there can be any ambiguity, based on the context

Comment: The first seems to be common in US, the second - in France (and few other European countries, big and small). The advantage of the second notation is that you cannot mistake it for the ordered pair notation $(a,b)$!

Comment: I agree that $(a,b)$ is _in theory_ confusing although _in practice_ there is rarely ever an issue.  I personally think that $]a,b[$ or $[a,b[$ look rather ugly compared to $(a,b)$ or $[a,b)$.

Comment: These questions are (to some extent) related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653425/whats-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-b

Comment: That is precisely the reason why the notation I was taught for intervals uses semicolons. Hence, $(a; b)$ for open interval, $[a; b]$ for closed, and so forth.