# Why $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty ]0,e^{-n}[=\emptyset$?

Tags: real-analysis

Why is:
$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty\,\mathopen{]}0,e^{-n}\mathclose{[}\,=\emptyset\quad?$$
Indeed,
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N, 0\in\mathopen{]}0,e^{-n}\mathclose{[},$$
and thus $0\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty\,\mathopen{]}0,e^{-n}\mathclose{[}$. So, what's wrong here ?

Comment: You are misreading the notation $]a,b[$.  The reversed brackets indicate the endpoints are *excluded*, synonymous with $(a,b)$.

Comment: I think $(a,b)$ is also preferable, because $]a,b[$ looks a bit messy somehow.

Comment: I've always used this notation, how is it messy?

Comment: I also dislike the notation $]a,b[$. I think it probably looks "messy" because I'm not used to seeing anything bracketed with the brackets "pointing outwards". Similarly, despite it not having a mathematical meaning (at least not to me) $)a,b($ looks weird.

Comment: $]a,b[$ is a standard notation for French people.

Comment: Unluckily, here in Italy many people use $]a,b[$ too. I prefer the notation $(a,b)$, but I do not believe that the former is "messy".

Comment: As someone who had never encountered reversed-bracket notation before, my immediate thought was that $]a, b[$ must mean the complement of $(a, b)$: that is, it represented $(-\infty, a] \cup [b, \infty)$. (I am now aware that the notation is standard in places.)

Comment: This notation was introduced by Bourbaki and became standard in France. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals

Answer (score 8):

> $$\forall n\in\mathbb N, 0\in ]0,e^{-n}[$$

This is wrong. $0\notin ]0,e^{-n}[$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to show that if $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty\neq \emptyset$ which means $\exists x\in\mathbb{R},\,x\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty]0,\,e^{-n}[$ then $\exists m\in\mathbb{N},\,e^{-m}<x$ and so $x\notin]0,\,e^{-m}[$ which leads to a contradiction. Note that since $x\in\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty]0,\,e^{-n}[$ then in particular $x\in ]0,1[$ and so $x>0$. Use the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}e^{-n}=0$.

Comment: This answer actually does not adress the actual problem OP had. I.e., OP is confused why $0\in]0,e^{-n}[$

Comment: @5xum You are indeed right, however one can see it as an interesting complement to Augustin's answer.

Comment: @5xum I wrote this after Augustin's answer who already explained why $0$ isn't in that set. But here I explain why this set is $\emptyset$.