# Is a Square Bracket Used in Intervals of Increase/Decrease?

Tags: functions, notation

For example, the I.O.I of y=x^2 is (0,infinite), with the round brackets meaning that the value is excluded. Are there any scenarios where a square bracket would be used when stating the intervals of increase/ decrease for a function? If it narrows it down, the only functions I deal with are: linear, exponential, quadratic, root, reciprocal, sinusoidal, and absolute

Comment: Can you define what an "interval of increase" is? Is it just the interval on which the function is increasing? Also, using abbreviations in questions (especially the first time you use the term" can make questions harder to read for people who don't know that (non-standard) terminology.

Comment: The function $x^2$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$, actually.

Comment: Wow! It's amazing to know how complicated the world is out there.

Comment: Interval of increase are the intervals (of x) when the y value increases. So my above example would mean that y increases between but not including those two x values (0 and infinity). Sorry about that

Comment: See also: [Notation for intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430851)

Answer (score 1):

For $a,b\in\mathbb R,a<b$, real intervals are defined as follows:
$$(a,b):=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid a<x<b\}$$
$$(a,b]:=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid a<x\leq b\}$$
$$[a,b):=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid a\leq x<b\}$$
$$[a,b]:=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid a\leq x\leq b\}$$
Each function is defined on domain. If the domain is a subset of $\mathbb R$ that contains intervals, you can ask which behavior the function has on these intervals.

For example, $f(x)=x^2,x\in\mathbb R$

- is increasing on any interval $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $(a,\infty)$, $[a,\infty)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $0\leq a<b$ (these are all intervals on which $f$ increases) and
- decreasing on any interval $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $[a,b]$, $(\infty,b)$, $(\infty,b]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, $a<b\leq 0$ (these are all intervals an which $f$ decreases).

Comment: Right you are: so, the squaring function is increasing on $[0.\infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$. At first, paradoxical, but not when you recognize, as you have here, that increasingness happens *on a set*, not at a point. Plus one.