# Does ⋮ mean "is divisible by" in mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

For example, $5(2+3m)⋮5$ if $m$ is an integer. My teacher said yes, but I can't find anything about this triple colon ⋮ online.

Comment: It’s certainly not a common usage. But notation is not universal, and if your professor defines it, that’s what it means in the class, but only in the class.

Comment: ok hmm. What is the usual way of writing it then? It may be awkward if in an exam the marker doesn't know what it means

Comment: The only way in normal notation to write it is $5\mid 5(2+3m).$ I don’t know of a standard symbol for “a is divisible by b.”

Comment: This is also new to me. Maybe he meant to say "is a multiple of..."? Either way, I have not seen the triple colon notation.

Comment: Yes, is a multiple of is also true. So does it mean "is a multiple of" but not necessarily "is divisible by"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brief examination of Belarusian, Russian, and Ukrainian Wikipedia pages corresponding to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor suggests that the triple colon "⋮" is a widespread notation meaning "is divisible by" or "is a multiple of" (which are the same). That is,

- "$a⋮b$",
- "$b\mid a$",
- "$\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}:a=nb$",
- "$a \mod  b = 0$", and
- "$a = 0\,\pmod b$"

are all equivalent.

In my opinion, the triple colon notation makes sense and is intuitive, just like the "[French brackets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals)".

Your teacher probably comes from the former Soviet Union.

Comment: thanks! Just curious however, what makes you think it is intuitive?

Comment: @user71207 I look at $\div$ and see the horizontal bar dividing something into two parts. I look at " ⋮ " and see that something is divided into three equal parts. Also, of all the expressions I listed, $b \mid a$ is the only one in which $b$ precedes $a$, which might be confusing. Notation " ⋮ " allows you to write the dividend before the divisor, as we normally do.

Comment: I had thought that you can say "$\exists z \in \mathbb{Z} : a = zb$"? Not just $\mathbb{N}$