# Who decided to use $(a, b)$ for open intervals and $[a, b]$ for closed intervals?

Tags: notation, math-history

The use of $$(a,b)$$ as an abbreviation for $$\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a<x<b\}$$
and $$[a,b]$$ as an abbreviation for $$\{x\in\Bbb R\mid a≤x≤b\}$$ is so widespread and so entrenched that I was surprised when I realized it was essentially arbitrary.

A student asked me what it was that way and I got halfway through mumbling something like “It's because closed sets have sharp edges and open sets have fuzzy ones” before I realized that was nonsense: Under this theory $(a,b)$ for a closed interval makes as much sense as $[a,b]$, because closed discs and open rectangles are just as common as open discs and closed rectangles. If the two types of brackets had been switched, back at the beginning of time, I don't think anyone would find have found it less intuitive, if this were the explanation.

I think what I was getting at perhaps is that one can imagine that the $($ curves toward the endpoint, and then away from it again without quite getting there, whereas the $[$ goes directly to the endpoint and stays there for a while.  I don't know if that was the intended intuition.  Or, indeed, if there was any intended intuition.  It's quite possible that whoever invented this notation needed two kinds of brackets and arbitrarily assigned one to each type of interval.  Or perhaps one of the notations was already well-established, and much later someone else wanted an analogous notation for the other kind of interval, and simply used a different kind of bracket.

Do we know anything about this?  I did not find anything with a Math SE or MO search, and I also looked at [Jeff Miller's site](https://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html), but did not find anything.  I have not checked Cajori, but it does not really seem like the kind of thing he covers.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but do you not think that it would be received better in the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange?

Comment: My experience has been that users here know a good deal more about the history of science and mathematics, and give better answers, than users there.

Comment: An alternative would be $]a,b[$ for open intevals. Pro: no confusion with ordered pairs, even more intuitive in describing whether the endpoints are in or out. Con: these being reversed brackets, the reader may be confused about how to parse a formula.

Comment: Related: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/142/why-is-american-and-french-notation-different-for-open-intervals-x-y-vs-x

Comment: Yes, thanks.  My question is not about the $]a,b[$ notation.  @Joe: Thanks for the link; I didn't think to search HSM, which was a silly thing to forget.  However, the linked post does not have any information about my question.  It does identify Bourbaki as the perpetrator of $]a,b[$ (which I knew) but has no other information about $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$.

Comment: A similar, but broader, question from 2013: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430851/notation-for-intervals. There are a few answers, but currently none which address your specific question.